# Magento 2 Plugin Sort Order

Tags: magento2, plugin

I am trying to understand the concept of sort order when using the plugin.

As per my understanding, the sort order works in lower to higher when used before method and higher to lower when used in after method. [As per official doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)
This works as expected when I use scenario 1 but not when I use scenario 2.

**Scenario 1**

I had used plugin for Product Model Class

**Product A Plugin (Sort Order 10)**

```
namespace Priyank\PluginA\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function beforeGetName($subject)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Before Execute From Plugin A');
    }
    
    public function aroundGetName($subject, $proceed)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Around Before Proceed Execute From Plugin A');
        
        $return = $proceed();
        
        $logger->info('Around After Proceed Execute From Plugin A');
        
        return $return;
    }

    public function afterGetName($subject, $result)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('After Execute From Plugin A');
        return $result;
    }    
}
```

**Product B Plugin (Sort Order 20)**

```
namespace Priyank\PluginB\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function beforeGetName($subject)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Before Execute From Plugin B');
    }

    public function aroundGetName($subject, $proceed)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Around Before Proceed Execute From Plugin B');

        $return = $proceed();

        $logger->info('Around After Proceed Execute From Plugin B');

        return $return;
    }

    public function afterGetName($subject, $result)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PluginTest.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('After Execute From Plugin B');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**The output is as expected**

```
PluginA::BeforeGetName()
    PluginA::aroundGetName() // Magento calls the first half until callable
PluginB::BeforeGetName()
    PluginB::aroundGetName() // Magento calls the first half until callable
        Action::dispatch()
    PluginB::aroundGetName() // Magento calls the Second half until callable
PluginB::afterGetName()
    PluginA::aroundGetName() // Magento calls the Second half until callable
PluginA::afterGetName()
```

**Scenario 2**
Just removed the around method in both the rest of the plugins remain the same.

**Output**

```
PluginA::BeforeGetName()
PluginB::BeforeGetName()
PluginA::afterGetName()
PluginB::afterGetName()
```

Here I was expecting Plugin B After called first as it has higher sort order. But when around was not used Plugin A after was called first. Why?

Comment: What if you add Product C Plugin (Sort Order 30).  Is it 10, 20, 30 for before, around, and after?

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Comment: I was curious.  What if you add a new Product C Plugin (Sort Order 30).  What is the order?

Answer (score 1):

Because its mistake of official documentation. I've checked dev and master branch of version 2.3.

So plugin without 'around' have prio for 'after' method due to sort order it has.

Please check

```
Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList:getNext()
```

returns next result in case of 2 plugins with around for PluginB only:

```
array (
    1 => //before 
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',                 
            1 => 'PluginB(20)',         
        ),
    4 => //after
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',
            1 => 'PluginB(20)',
        ),
    2 => 'PluginB(20)', //around    
)
```

returns next result in case of 3 plugins with around for PluginC only:

```
array (
    1 => //before 
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',                 
            1 => 'PluginB(20)',     
            2 => 'PluginC(30)', 
        ),
    4 => //after
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',
            1 => 'PluginB(20)',
            2 => 'PluginC(30)', 
        ),
    2 => 'PluginC(30)', //around    
)
```

returns next result in case of 3 plugins, each has his own around:

```
array (
    1 => //before 
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',                 
        ),
    4 => //after
        array (
            0 => 'PluginA(10)',
        ),
    2 => 'PluginA(10)', //around    
)

array (
    1 => //before 
        array (
            0 => 'PluginB(20)',                 
        ),
    4 => //after
        array (
            0 => 'PluginB(20)',
        ),
    2 => 'PluginB(20)', //around    
)

array (
    1 => //before 
        array (
            0 => 'PluginC(30)',                 
        ),
    4 => //after
        array (
            0 => 'PluginC(30)',
        ),
    2 => 'PluginC(30)', //around    
)
```

So in this case official documentation is wrong telling that PluginA without 'around' will be executed after PluginB.

It happens because rest plugins methods('after' and 'before') inside plugins without 'around' merged by Interceptor to the next sorted plugin(to his interception method list) that has 'around' to not lose next callable if exists, keeping their sorted order at execution time.

```
Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList:_inheritPlugins() Ln:189
```

One thing is not clear for me why they haven't fixed this yet?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As Per My understanding.

Before, Around and After executes by Asc Order.

The difference for your question can be understand by this picture.

Around creates a nesting for all the higher sort order plugins. Followed by further nesting.

If you remove around plugins there will be no nesting and before After will be executed by Asc Order.

Also if $callable is not called from around from Plugin A it will terminates other higher order plugins.

If $callable is called It nest the higher sort order plugins and executes until the scope is finished.